# Get Group by and count on Array field in PostgreSQL Jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have my table like this

| user_Id | survey |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | {"What are you interested in?": "[Games]", "How do you plan to use Gamester?": "[Play games, Watch other people play, Connect with other gamers]" } |
| 1001 | {"What are you interested in?": "[Coupons]", "How do you plan to use Gamester?": "[Watch other people play]" } |
| 1001 | {"What are you interested in?": "[Games]", "How do you plan to use Gamester?": "[Play games]" } |

I want to group by second field `How do you plan to use Gamester?` And have output like below

| Option | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Play games | 2 |
| Watch other people play | 2 |
| Connect with other gamers | 1 |

All the examples I found were for String fields and not for array. Tried few thing but not working. Kindly help how can I group on array field values in josonb column and get count.

Answer (score 1):

Your json data array in the `How do you plan to use Gamester?` property is wrong. Since you are storing a string and not an array of values.

Replace all values ​​as shown below:

Source Format: `"[Play games, Watch other people play, Connect with other gamers]"`

Required Format: `["Play games", "Watch other people play", "Connect with other gamers"]`

---

After fixing your data, you can use the jsonb_path_query function and return a list of values ​​from the desired property, and then group them.

```
with cte_plan as (
  select
  jsonb_path_query(survey, '$."How do you plan to use Gamester?"[*]') as option
  from my_table
)
select option, count(option) from cte_plan group by option;
```

Result

| option | count |
| --- | --- |
| Watch other people play | 2 |
| Play games | 2 |
| Connect with other gamers | 1 |

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=aff25687438afcb75fbffcf7f03788f0)